# Quasar application cannot connect to heroku socket.io server

Tags: node.js, vue.js, heroku, socket.io, quasar-framework

I am trying to connect my quasar application to a socket.io express server hosted on heroku.
The problem is that every time I try to connect, the browser says [the request is pending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al3gh.png) and on the backend I never receive the message of connection.

**This is my backend code**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORTA || 3000;
const server = app
  .use((req, res) => {})
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}...`));

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true
  }
});

io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('Connected: ' + socket.id);
});
```

**And this is the connection in a boot file in quasar (vue.js) with socket.io extended**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueSocketIOExt from 'vue-socket.io-extended';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io(URL_CONNECTION);

Vue.use(VueSocketIOExt, socket);
```

As you can see on the backend I have a console.log to see the id of the connected client. If I try this locally in my pc it works fine and I get the socket id, but on heroku the client doesn't connect without giving me any error.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this. I just removed the custom port I inserted in the server and I put the default (process.env.PORT) and then I connected from the client giving the port 80.

Now, I don't know why, but it's working.